# Get child component inside of a @ChildComponent Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, children

I'm trying to get a children component of another component, is it possible? For example, I have this QueryList:

```
@ContentChildren(SysColumn) syscolumns: QueryList<SysColumn>;
```

It will create a QueryList of all the SysColumns classes instanciated, that's perfectp, but i need to get a list of the child components inside of SysColums... The HTML will be like this:

```
<parent>    
 <sys-column>
  <child></child>
 </sys-column>
 <sys-column>
   <child></child>
 </sys-column>
</parent>
```

If I do a Foreach of the QueryList it will show the two SysColms, but now I need to have the inner components. How can I achieve it

Comment: I already declare it in the father component, i need to have something like a ContentChildren that i can access trough the father component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here on the angular GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11039#issuecomment-242091301

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query Child components, `@ContentChildren()` needs to look like

```
@ContentChildren(Child, {descendants: true}) children: QueryList<Child>;
```

`{descendants: true}` might be the default anyway (don't remember)

Comment: I think it doesn work on different levels of projection.

Comment: Works. Here is an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/xnrladsMCqnhXzPUhg5q?p=preview. descendants is false by default.